# Примитивы для обобщеных типов

Tags: generics, rust, типы

Прочитав главы "Rust Programming Language", про обобщенные типы, появился вопрос, есть ли в Rust обобщения для примитивных типов? В C++ например у шаблонов при обьявлении есть обобпщения `typename`, пример

```
template <typename T>
void example(T param) {
   //code
}
```

И теперь функция сможет принять любой примитивный тип, так же для обобщений есть `<class T>`.

В Rust'же, мы можем давать обобщениям ограничения по типажам, но как давать обобщениям ограничения по примтивным типам? Просто например если мы не укажим ограничения обобщению вообще, пользовать мы ним не сможем, потому что на момент обьявления, мы точно не знаем есть ли на `T` операции как для числовых типов, например.

```
fn example<T>(param: T) {
    param + 1//error
}

example(12);
```

То есть мы не можем нормально указать функции что обобщения будет любого численого типа, но мы можем ограничить обобпщение по трейту, например

```
trait Test {
   fn test(&self);
}

fn example<T: Test>(t: T) {
    t.test//working
}
```

Ну в итоге главный вопрос, как дать обобщенному типу ограничение по примитивному типу? Например по всем числиным типам. Возможно ли это? Или надо писать трейт который будет реализовываться для `i32` например? Или это не имеет смысла?

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке есть типажи вроде `ops::Add` и т.п. Если нужно что-то более точное, то обычно используют типажи из пакета https://docs.rs/num - https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=18b275930d8a934f42f635fc8994fdca.

Comment: То есть мы можем ограничивать только по типажам, которые косят под обычные примитивные типы? Похоже это то что надо. Спасибо. Если бы вы дали такой ответ, я бы выбрал его как удовлетворяющий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандартной библиотеке есть типажи вроде `ops::Add` и т.п. Если нужно что-то более точное, то обычно используют типажи из пакета https://docs.rs/num:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=18b275930d8a934f42f635fc8994fdca

```
extern crate num;

use num::PrimInt;
use std::iter::Product;

/// Find the factorial of n
fn factorial<T>(n: T) -> T
where
    T: PrimInt + Product,
{
    num::range(T::one(), n + T::one()).product()
}

fn main() {
    let a: u8 = factorial(3);
    println!("u8 = {}", a);
    let b: i32 = factorial(4);
    println!("i32 = {}", b);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, ещё раз.